# center-block with btn-group on mobile

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying center align a div block and it works great on web but on mobile, not so much :(

Here's my code:

```
    <div class="center-block">
        <div class="btn-group">
        <label class="btn btn-success vertical-align" ng-model="checkModel.left" btn-checkbox>1</label>
        <label class="btn btn-success vertical-align" ng-model="checkModel.middle" btn-checkbox>2 and Best and all</label>
        <label class="btn btn-success vertical-align" ng-model="checkModel.left" btn-checkbox>3</label>
        <label class="btn btn-success vertical-align" ng-model="checkModel.middle" btn-checkbox>4</label>
        <label class="btn btn-success vertical-align" ng-model="checkModel.left" btn-checkbox>5</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any way out?

Comment: We need to see your css

Comment: This is the standard bootstrap 3 css. Nothing is added except "vertical-align" class which can be ignored.

Comment: Can you post the full code? Current code is not centered in web as well. http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/pxezgLnw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change center-block into text-center to make it work.

```
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-success vertical-align" ng-model="checkModel.left" btn-checkbox>1</label>
    <label class="btn btn-success vertical-align" ng-model="checkModel.middle" btn-checkbox>2 and Best and all</label>
    <label class="btn btn-success vertical-align" ng-model="checkModel.left" btn-checkbox>3</label>
    <label class="btn btn-success vertical-align" ng-model="checkModel.middle" btn-checkbox>4</label>
    <label class="btn btn-success vertical-align" ng-model="checkModel.left" btn-checkbox>5</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bmpzcapt/

Comment: I tried with text-center earlier but it didn't work. I tried now and it magically started working!! I guess it's because of the conflict with other classes that i deleted just now. Thank You :)

Comment: Glad I could be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

I used bootply and I believe the problem comes from the text (best and all ...) so a work around this is to hide it at small screens using span and showing only best maybe?

```
<div class="center-block">
        <div class="btn-group">
        <label class="btn btn-success vertical-align" ng-model="checkModel.left" btn-checkbox>1</label>
        <label class="btn btn-success vertical-align" ng-model="checkModel.middle" btn-checkbox>2 
         <span class="hidden-xs">and</span> Best <span class="hidden-xs">and all</span></label>
        <label class="btn btn-success vertical-align" ng-model="checkModel.left" btn-checkbox>3</label>
        <label class="btn btn-success vertical-align" ng-model="checkModel.middle" btn-checkbox>4</label>
        <label class="btn btn-success vertical-align" ng-model="checkModel.left" btn-checkbox>5</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u1ujsn5j/1/)